# Set width of an element using offsetWidth property with raw javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a content slider carousel with pure javascript, this carousel must be responsive, and for that, I'm using a few variables to set and get element width.

So I get the container width called 'slider', using .offsetWidth and after that, I'm using a loop that set each slide width with the same width of the container. For to be easy for anyone to understand here's my HTML

```js
function createSlider(id) {
  var slider = document.getElementById(id),
    sliderContainerWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth),
    ul = document.getElementById("carrousel"),
    ulLength = ul.children.length,
    i = 0;

  console.log(sliderWidth);

  function setUlWidth() {
    ul.style.width = (sliderContainerWidth * ulLength);
  }

  function setLiWidth() {
    for (i; i < ulLength; i++) {
      ul.children[i].style.width = sliderContainerWidth;
      //console.log(sliderContainerWidth)
    }
  }
  setUlWidth();
  setLiWidth();
}
createSlider('slider');
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul id="carrousel">
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If I try to set using offsetWidth nothing happen but if I use a fixed value work's fine.

anyone can help me?

Comment: I believe your css is needed too, where <div id="slider"> take his width?

Comment: When I run your snippet, I get an error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: sliderWidth is not defined"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style.width` needs to be set with a string that includes a unit marker, in this case "px" for pixels:

```
  function setUlWidth() {
    ul.style.width = (sliderContainerWidth * ulLength) +"px";
  }

  function setLiWidth() {
    for (i; i < ulLength; i++) {
      ul.children[i].style.width = sliderContainerWidth + "px";
      console.log(sliderContainerWidth)
    }
  }
```

In addition, FWIW, the [`offsetWidth` property of Element nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) is a number which has been rounded to the nearest integer already - you don't need to convert it from a string using `parsInt`.

Comment: Thank's it's really what I need